# How to connect to AWS Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm trying to connect to AWS Elasticsearch but I always get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:278)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:197)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.index(AbstractClient.java:98)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.index(TransportClient.java:334)
at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequestBuilder.doExecute(IndexRequestBuilder.java:313)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
at com.c_backendcrawler.utility.ElasticSearch.uploadObject(ElasticSearch.java:25)
at com.c_backendcrawler.Start.main(Start.java:34)
```

My code is following:

```
 //Create Client
    Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "zencubes-search").put("node.name","Darkhawk").build();
    TransportClient transportClient = new TransportClient(settings);
    transportClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
            "x.x.x.x",9300));
    return transportClient;
```

Output from AWS Elasticsearch:

```
    {
status: 200,
name: "Darkhawk",
cluster_name: "817880037706:zencubes-search",
version: {
number: "1.5.2",
build_hash: "62ff9868b4c8a0c45860bebb259e21980778ab1c",
build_timestamp: "2015-04-27T09:21:06Z",
build_snapshot: false,
lucene_version: "4.10.4"
},
tagline: "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I tried to curl (https://search-zencubes-search-xxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com/ ) and it works - but not on port 9300. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is port 9300 open on that AWS instance?

Comment: its not open - but i think i have searched everything through and i didn't find a setting to change that - i don't know if aws uses a different default port.

Ah and i'm using the aws elasticsearch service - not a manually configured ec2 instance

Comment: Looks like you may need to configure an access policy: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-gsg.html

Comment: Might be something :) Do you have an example of a complete open access policy (since this is just a test)?

Comment: IAM policy generator: http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Comment: Thanks ;) I will come back when it works!

Comment: I changed the policy to accept everything - still not working :( I tried it now with a local installation and my code seems to be fine since it instantly worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The native transport protocol is not support using AWS Managed ElasticSearch and is only available over the REST endpoint.  Consider switching your client to consume the REST endpoint, such as https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest.

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=681938

Comment: Thanks a lot - i will have a look at it later this day and come back to you :)

Answer (score 7):

[Since the Elasticsearch Java SDK version 5.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/release-notes-5.6.0.html) there is a [REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html) available. This allows you to connect to Elasticsearch Service on AWS.

Currently Elasticsearch Service allows installations up to version 5.5, but you can use the 5.6 Java SDK against a 5.5 cluster with minor limitations.

**Note**: When initializing the `RestClient` you should use the port `80` or `443` respectively instead of the `9200`. E.g.

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
    new HttpHost("search-test-elasti-xxxx-xxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com", 80, "http")).build();
RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(restClient); 
// [...]
```

Comment: how do you sign the request though?

Answer (score 3):

## How to get the AWS ES URL

Go to the Elasticsearch Domain console and get the Endpoint in the Overview tab.

Port to use is 443.

[image]

Make sure the access control has been configured.

- [Options for granting or denying access to Amazon ES endpoints](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-control-access-to-your-amazon-elasticsearch-service-domain/)

[image]

---

### FYI

#### Create an Elasticsearch Index

```
curl -v -XPUT "${ES_ENDPOINT}/article/" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1,
            "number_of_replicas" : 0
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

As John Russell said above, you need to use a REST client to communicate with your AWS Elastic cluster.

Elastic recently released the first RC version of its own Java REST client, so this is an option now as well.

Client Docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html

Maven Repo:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.elasticsearch.client%22%20AND%20a%3A%22rest%22